# LINQ: How to return all children elements of all parents

Tags: c#, linq

I have `IEnumerable<Parent> AllParents`. Each parent has `IEnumerable<Child> Children`. How can I extract all children of all parents into one `IEnumerable<Child> AllChildren` using LINQ?

Foreach way I'm using now:

```
var allChildrenList = new List<Child>();
foreach (var parent in AllParents)
{
    allChildrenList.AddRange(parent.Children);
}
AllChildren = allChildrenList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0),

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
> the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
var allChildrens = AllParents.SelectMany(x => x.Children).ToList();
```

It will iterate over all parents and combine children of all parents to a single list.